# Having Bootstrap to show the whole page instead of zooming it on a mobile device?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for a website and I notice that when I view my layout on a mobile device, my mobile's web browser automatically zooms in to a particular top left corner portion of the webpage. I want the browser to show the whole webpage at start instead of zooming into the top left corner. Showing the whole webpage (albeit may be a little small in size) is the default behaviour when I don't use Bootstrap.

Is it possible to get Bootstrap to show the whole webpage instead of zooming in to the page when first entering it on a mobile device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely has to do with the viewport being set. Assuming your webpage is a standard size, you can use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">
```

make sure to place that in the head of your page - or replace the one that is currently there.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for the Viewport html tag: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it by removing the viewport meta code from your . This worked in my application. If you want to have it correct for your device, put this in into head tags.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive